# golang, create a variable from another one

Tags: go, reflection

I want to :

1. Create a variable with the type of another one. The source variable is numeric (int, int16, float32, ...)
2. Make some simple operations (+, -, ...) on this variable.

This code works fine :

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

func init1(v interface{}) interface{} {
    switch reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind() {
        case reflect.Int:
            return int(0)
        case reflect.Float32:
            return float32(0)
        case reflect.Float64:
            return float64(0)
    }
    return nil
}

func sum(x, y interface{}) interface{} {
    switch reflect.ValueOf(x).Kind() {
        case reflect.Int:
            return x.(int) + y.(int)
        case reflect.Float32:
            return x.(float32) + y.(float32)
        case reflect.Float64:
            return x.(float64) + y.(float64)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    v0 := 222.33
    x0 := init1(v0)
    x0 = sum(x0, v0)
    x0 = sum(x0, v0)
    fmt.Printf("v=%v, x=%v type x=%T\n", v0, x0, x0)

    v1 := 33
    x1 := init1(v1)
    x1 = sum(x1, v1)
    x1 = sum(x1, v1)
    fmt.Printf("v=%v, x=%v type x=%T\n", v1, x1, x1)
}
```

Result :

```
v=222.33, x=444.66 type x=float64
v=33, x=66 type x=int
```

Is there a more elegant solution (without the two switch blocks) to do the same job ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more elegant solution (without the two switch blocks) to do the same job ?

No there is not.

You could use reflection but would still need a switch for int, uints and floats.

(Btw: Don't do such things.)

Answer (score 0):

There is more elegant and more effective solution - do not use `interface{}` as casting to/from interface{} will result in spending resources (CPU/memory) on boxing/unboxing.

```
// Bad solution - 11 lines of slow code
func sumBad(x, y interface{}) interface{} {
    switch reflect.ValueOf(x).Kind() {
        case reflect.Int:
            return x.(int) + y.(int)
        case reflect.Float32:
            return x.(float32) + y.(float32)
        case reflect.Float64:
            return x.(float64) + y.(float64)
    }
    return nil
}

// Good solution - 9 lines of code that works faster
func sumInt(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
func sumFloat32(a, b float32) float32 {
    return a + b
}
func sumFloat64(a, b float64) float64 {
    return a + b
}
```

If you have much more code inside the function you can use [Go code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate) to generate the functions for as many types as you want.

Another alternative would be to choose a type that cover all your needs. For example can you use just `float64` and cast parameters to it whenever needed?